# Fullcalendar days start and end customization

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar and i want to do something a little bit weird.
I need to have my days starting at 5:00 and ending at 5:00 (next day).

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: okay mate, which language it is programed? some info about the programming questions is needed, like specific code that declares that start time of the day?

Comment: Sorry, Fullcalendar is a JavaScript library. My project is developed with (Symfony PHP framework)

Answer (score 0):

I think firstHour might be what you're looking for.

Here is the fullCalendar [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/firstHour/)

Comment: Sorry but firstHour is not for that